# How to override an imported module in nestjs testing?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm quite new on `nestjs`, met an issue regarding how to override the `load` function of `ConfigModule`, hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

My e2e testing:

```js
const moduleForTesting = await Test.createTestingModule({imports: [AppModule]});
```

My App Module:

```js
import config from './config/index'

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true, load: [config]})]
})
```

My `config/index` file:

```js
export default async () => {
  someConfigs: ...
}
```

Now I want the e2e testings use another configurations, but I don't know how to override the AppModule, nor the `load` function:

```js
// AppModule
import config from './config/index' // This is ok for production, but need to be overridden in testing

...
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true, load: [config]})]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095261/overriding-providers-in-nestjs-jest-tests?

Comment: Thank you @milo526, but I still don't know how to do it. Because the link you provided seems to use `overrideProvider`, but I need to `overrideModule`, which method is not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the elegant NestJs way to do that, but after a deep breath, I reconsidered what I really want to do and then found a hackie way to achieve that.

I need to mock the `config` file so that during testing, the `load` array will be mocked, where the `jest.mock` comes to the rescue:

```js
// e2e testing file

jest.mock('../src/config/index', () => ({
    default: async () => ({
        someConfigs: 'mocked config'
    })
})) // <--- By putting the `jest.mock` before the `createTestingModule`, the `load` array will be mocked.

...
const moduleForTesting = await Test.createTestingModule({imports: [AppModule]});
```

Answer (score 2):

See `withModule` method in `TestModuleBuilder` from [@jbiskur/nestjs-test-utilities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jbiskur/nestjs-test-utilities)

NestJS feature request: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4905

Comment: Looks like this is [scheduled](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/8777) for 10.0.0. great work. Will look into it more but do you know off hand what the difference is when using overrideProvider vs specifying a provider in the array when created the testing module ?

Comment: Quick search seems like I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000993/nestjs-overrideprovider-vs-provider-in-unit-testing)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overridProvider`

```
const moduleForTesting = await Test.createTestingModule({imports: [AppModule]}).overrideProvider(MyService).useValue(myServiceMock).compile()
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to override module import is by using `TestingModuleBuilder` method `overrideModule`, it works also for `overrideGuard`, `overrideInterceptor`, `overrideProvider` ...

So first put your config in const or var and export it

```js
export const config = ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true, load: [config]});
@Module({
  imports: [
    config 
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

In your test create new config module

```js
const testConfig = ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: false, load: []});

const builder = Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule]
});
const override = builder.overrideModule(config);
override.useModule(testConfig);
const moduleFixture = await builder.compile();
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
await app.init();
```

In case of non `DynamicModule` use Type directly for example for `OtherModule` do

```js
const builder = Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule]
});
const override = builder.overrideModule(OtherModule);
override.useModule(TestOtherModule);
const moduleFixture = await builder.compile();
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
await app.init();
```