# Nestjs overrideProvider vs provider in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I see two ways of mocking services in NestJS for unit testing, the first one is the same as we define providers in real modules like:

```js
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    UserService,
    {
      provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
      useValue: mockUsersRepository,
    }
  ],
}).compile();
```

And the other way with `overrideProvider` method. As following:

```js
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [UserModule]
})
.overrideProvider(getRepositoryToken(User))
.useValue(mockUsersRepository)
.compile();
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is pretty simple.

With the first approach (array of providers), you create **custom testing module** to test (probably) the `UserService`.

With second approach, you use **complete module** in the very same shape as it is used in the application itself.

The result is exactly the same - your mock is being injected  into the constructor of `UserService`.

The first approach is better for small, mostly unit tests, but these tests can be also done without using NestJS test tooling at all (just pass mock manually to the ctor), while the second one does a great job in integration tests.

Repository is not great example to use to explain, but think about `Logger`.
You are performing some integration tests of 2 or more modules.
You do not want to manually create big testing module (which also is breaking the connection with real shape of your modules), but you want to just import your modules which are being tested together and `.overrideProvider` for `Logger` with e.g. `loggerMock` which lets you to assert all logger calls across all tested modules.

Example:

```js
@Module({providers: [LoggerService], exports: [LoggerService]})
export class LoggerModule {}

@Module({imports: [LoggerModule], providers: [FooService]})
export class FooModule {}

@Module({imports: [LoggerModule], providers: [BarService]})
export class BarModule {}

@Module({imports: [FooModule, BarModule]}
export class AppModule {}

// TEST
const testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  import: [AppModule]
})
  .overrideProvider(LoggerService)
  .useValue(/* your logger mock will be provided in both FooService and BarService and you can easily test all related to logs then */)
  .compile();
```

I hope it is clear. If not, please leave a comment and I will try to explain more.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. I just didn't realize the last part. (Logger module). Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Provided more explanation, but unfortunately, I see you already accepted another answer...

Comment: Thank you so much. And one question, what would've happened if I'd used provider instead of overrideProvider in your example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, in your example, what happens if we use `provider` in `createTestingModule` instead of using `overrideProvider`?

Comment: It will not be overridden inside the modules then.

Comment: So, you mean `LoggerService` will be a part of AppModule, and in other modules, they're going to use their own `LoggerService`, Is it right?

Comment: I guess your explanations and examples make more sense. Therefore, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

So let me try to explain it this way:
`overrideProvider` is useful when you've imported an entire module and need to override something it has as a provider. A use case, like the answer mentioned, would be overriding a logger. So say you have

```js
const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  import: [AuthModule]
}).compile();
```

And assume that `AuthModule` has `imports: [ LoggerModule ]`. In our test, we don't really want to see all the logs created, but we can't provide a custom provider for the `LoggerService` because it's being imported and used via the `LoggerModule` (overriding an injection token isn't really a common practice). So to provide our own implementation for`LoggerService` (let's say we just need a noop `log` method) we can do the following

```js
const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  import: [AuthModule]
})
  .overrideProvider(LoggerService)
  .useValue({ log: () => { /* noop */ } })
  .compile();
```

And now when our `AuthService` calls `this.logger.log()` it will just call this `noop` and be done with it.

On the flip side, if we're doing unit testing, usually you don't need to `overrideProvider` because you just set up the `provider` and the custom provider directly in the testing module's metadata and use that.

The `overrideProvider` is really useful when you *have* to use `imports` (like integration and e2e tests), otherwise, generally, it's better to use a custom provider